# ESLint rule to detect nested assignments

Tags: eslint

There seems to be no ESLint rule to detect nested variable assignments. This is a very common mistake.

```
function assert (cond) {
   if (!cond) {
      throw new Error("Assertion failed.");
   }
}

function test () {
   let var1 = 1;
   assert(var1 = 2);         // mistake: assigns 2 to var1!
   console.log(var1);
}
```

I tried to propose a new rule at GitHub, but this is only possible when there is a related new ECMAScript feature. And I can't find an existing rule that could be extended accordingly. The `no-cond-assign` and `no-return-assign` rules are similar, but they would not be suitable for such an extension.

Comment: Since this would always return true (I assume) would `no-constant-condition` catch this? I am not 100% sure since this is utilizing assert.

Comment: I tested with `"extends": "eslint:all"` in the ESLint config file and there is no existing rule (with default options) that detects this problem.

Answer (score 0):

My question has been answered on [GitHub](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/16765) by [DMartens](https://github.com/DMartens) and [mdjermanovic](https://github.com/mdjermanovic).

The [no-restricted-syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax) rule can be used:

e.g.:

```
"no-restricted-syntax": ["error", {
  selector:
    "AssignmentExpression:not(
       ExpressionStatement > AssignmentExpression,
       ForStatement > AssignmentExpression.update )",
  message: "Do not nest assignments"
  }],
```

or

```
"no-restricted-syntax": ["error", {
  selector: ":not(ExpressionStatement, ForStatement) > AssignmentExpression",
  message: "Do not nest assignments"
  }],
```